# Align two mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two databases. WordpressDB and JoomlaDB

WordpressDB has table db1_users
JoomlaDB has table db2_users

thoose tables has the same fields names

```
id  | email | Login | Password
```

General database is WordpressDB.
So i need all `id` in JoomlaDB  make the same as `id` in WordpressDB where `email` field is the same.

So how to do that, it is about 10.000 entries?

Comment: Doing that will completely break Joomla. The ID is not there for you to muck with. It is a key used in all of the other tables. Instead of trying to join on id, try to join on email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is right or not, but if you're looking for query to update ID in table joomla using data ID in table wordpress, I think you can use this :

```
update WordpressDB.tbl_user1 
set WordpressDB.tbl_user1.ID=(
select JoomlaDB.tbl_user2.ID from JoomlaDB.tbl_user2 
where JoomlaDB.tbl_user2.EMAIL=WordpressDB.tbl_user1.EMAIL
)
```

Comment: problem is that two different databases and has different user names and passwords

Answer (score 1):

You can create a column `wp_user_id` in the table `db2_users` and create a migration script to map the user ids from WordpressDB `db1_users` to JoomlaDB where same mail exists.

In this way you wont affect how Joomla handles user ids and you can achieve your needs.

Just note that you may fall a victim of concurrent update since tow modules might update the same row at the same time, in this case you might need a [locking mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878672/how-to-lock-a-single-row) when updating user rows on JoomlaDB.

Comment: So how to look that migration  script?

Comment: You will need an UPDATE  query with join between the two databases as long as they are on the same server, where you set the wp_user_id in the JoomlaDb based on the email matching when joining the two tables by email... You can benefit from this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057565/mysql-update-statement-inner-join-tables) for more information about using updates with joins..