# How to conditional update SQL tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two database tables like so:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS accounts (
  id        INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  balance   INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transactions (
  from      INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES accounts(id),
  to        INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES accounts(id),
  amount    INT NOT NULL
)
```

In my application logic, whenever a new transaction request comes in, I want to check first if the from account has sufficient balance, then I want to subtract the amount from the from account, add amount to the to account, and add a new row to the transactions table.

However, I want to do all of this atomically, for two reasons:

- Prevent race conditions. If two requests come in to transfer $5 from account 1 to account 2, and account 1 only has $5 total, I want to prevent double spending of the balance. Thus, the checking of sufficient balance and subsequent updating of balances has to happen atomically.
- Prevent inconsistent state if application crashes.

Is it possible to do this in a single SQL statement? assume we are using Postgres.

I know for example I can do `UPDATE accounts SET balance = balance - 6 WHERE id = 1 and balance > 6;` to check if account has sufficient balance and simultaneously update the balance at the same time.

I've also heard of something called `select ... for update` but I'm not sure if this can help me here.

Also, the result of the query should indicate whether the transaction was successful, so I can display some error message to client if it is not?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples/17607619

Comment: *assume we are using PostGres.* If so then tag [postgresql] and untag [mysql].

Comment: @kmoser not really, this just shows how to use transactions. How does this solve my problem? I still need to have some way of checking if balance is sufficient before adding to the to account

Comment: @shmth Transactions let you treat multiple SQL statements as an atomic operation. Isn't that what you want to do?

Comment: @kmoser But I also want to prevent race conditions as I mentioned in the question. Transactions do not help with this, since two transactions can interleave.

Comment: @shmth You can lock the tables/rows before performing the transaction, to ensure only one process can access them at a time.

Comment: @kmoser how to I lock a single row for a transaction? I definitely don't want to lock the entire table, since let's imagine we have many many transactions happening per second and locking entire table would severely limit the throughput

Comment: @shmth [MySQL, update multiple tables with one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361774/mysql-update-multiple-tables-with-one-query) and [How to lock a single row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878672/how-to-lock-a-single-row/3878726)

Comment: @kmoser The second link is not helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is not to cram everything into a single SQL statement. Apart from being complicated, it will not necessarily protect you from race conditions.

Use database transactions. To avoid anomalies, either lock everything you read with `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` against concurrent modifications, or use the `REPEATABLE READ` Isolation level and repeat the transaction if you get a serialization error.

To protect yourself from deadlocks, make sure that you always lock the account with the lower `id` first.

Here is a pseudo-code example:

```
EXEC SQL START TRANSACTION;

if (id1 < id2) {
    EXEC SQL SELECT balance INTO :bal1 FROM accounts
         WHERE id = :id1 FOR UPDATE;
    EXEC SQL SELECT balance INTO :bal2 FROM accounts
         WHERE id = :id2 FOR UPDATE;
} else {
    EXEC SQL SELECT balance INTO :bal2 FROM accounts
         WHERE id = :id2 FOR UPDATE;
    EXEC SQL SELECT balance INTO :bal1 FROM accounts
         WHERE id = :id1 FOR UPDATE;
}

if (bal1 < amount) {
    EXEC SQL ROLLBACK;
    throw_error('too little money on account');
}

EXEC SQL UPDATE accounts SET balance = :bal1 - :amount WHERE id = :id1;
EXEC SQL UPDATE accounts SET balance = :bal1 + :amount WHERE id = :id2;
EXEC SQL INSERT INTO transaction ("from", "to", amount)
    VALUES (:id1, :id2, :amount);

EXEC SQL COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thanks, a couple followup questions:

1. how can I first check if the balance of first user is sufficient, before proceeding to make the updates to the tables?

2. Do the sql queries return some status so that I know whether the operation actually succeeded or not?

Comment: 1. Run a `SELECT`. 2. If a statement fails, it will always cause an error.

Comment: Are you able to provide an example of SQL statement? I still don't understand how I can do 1.

In pseudo code, I want something like:

```
select * from accounts where id = i;
if balance > 6:
  update accounts set balance = balance - 6 where id = 1
  update accounts set balance = balance + 6 where id = 2
  insert into transactions 1, 2, 6
```

Comment: Another option would be to not check sufficient balance in your code. Instead put a check constraint on the column.  So:  alter table accounts add constraint bal_ge_0 check (balance >= 0);